# Sorting in Jackson Library W/O POJO Specified

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, fasterxml

I would like to know how sorting in the jackson library works.
What I have is a json like the below(no POJO equivalent of this json exists), and I would like to sort the array 'ItemProps', even though sometimes it might contain the properties in different order.

```
{
  "ItemId":"<item_id>",
  "ItemProps":[
     {
       "key":"property_key",
       "value":"property_value"
     },
{
       "key":"property_key",
       "value":"property_value"
     }
   ]
```

After quite a bit of reading, I found that this can be achieved by creating a deterministic mapper object by setting the properties to true

1. ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS
2. SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY

I've wrote few unit tests and found it to be working as expected.
But I am wondering how the sorting of the ItemProps works internally?
Is it by

1. hashcode of the individual json objects
2. takes one or more fields as references and does comparison?

I searched about it and couldn't find anything on it.
Any pointers to any articles or answers will be helpful.
Thanks.

But I am still curios as to how this sorting works.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the source code from the jar file. I was curious & just took a look at jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar.

If you are not deserializing map to an instance of SortedMap, ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS will use a TreeMap to sort it out & return the sorted result.

```
 protected Map<?,?> _orderEntries(Map<?,?> input)
    {
        // minor optimization: may already be sorted?
        if (input instanceof SortedMap<?,?>) {
            return input;
        }
        return new TreeMap<Object,Object>(input);
    }
```

SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY will also sort the results using TreeMap.

```
int size = props.size();
Map<String, POJOPropertyBuilder> all;
// Need to (re)sort alphabetically?
if (sort) {
    all = new TreeMap<String,POJOPropertyBuilder>();
} else {
    all = new LinkedHashMap<String,POJOPropertyBuilder>(size+size);
}
```

Remember, this is internal & in later version implementation can change.

Comment: Thanks @aatwork, will take a look at it. Still curious as to what field from the JSON will be choosen to do the sorting. Deepdive should get to the answer.